# How to count website contact form submissions without database

Tags: php, counter

Hi I'm new here and have a question about SMTP mail PHP function.
I created a contact form which sends an HTML email to the company.

Now I've been asked to create a counter for every email sent from the web page, so they can know how many people are requesting information about the product. I read that is not possible without a database, which we're not using for this project, but I was thinking about doing it with an XML counter.

Is this the better way, or there's other possibilities for this?

Comment: Yes, the grass is always greener on the other side. And sure, there are a thousand other possibilities. - What is your concrete question? Which of the existing questions have not answered your question and why? Where have you read that it is not possible without a database? What qualifies a database for you? Is an XML file a database in your eyes? Why is there a preference for XML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you don't need xml. A simple file will do:

counts.txt:

```
0
```

counter_update.php:

```
<?php

$count = trim(file_get_contents('counts.txt'));
$count++;
file_put_contents('counts.txt', $count);
```

If your system is moderately busy, you may want to add in some file locking so two parallel mail scripts won't trash each other's count increments, but this is the basics of what you need.